# Are MongoDB indexes persistent across restarts?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Referencing the guide here, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/ I cannot tell if Mongo indexes for fields are stored persistently.

If `ensureIndex()` is called (and completes) within an application using `MongoDB`, what happens if:

1. The application using `MongoDB` is restarted.  Will a subsequent call to `ensureIndex()` cause a complete reindex?
2. The `MongoDB` server is restarted.  Would a later call of `ensureIndex()` from a client application rebuild?
3. Is any of this affected by having multiple client sessions?  I assume indexing is global across the entire collection per the documentation: `"MongoDB defines indexes on a per-collection level."`

Comment: do you have sharding or replication?

Comment: Would that affect any of these cases?  I was asking about the simple case, but you've piqued my interest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The application using MongoDB is restarted. Will a subsequent call to ensureIndex() cause a complete reindex?

No, it should (as in every other driver) register as a no op since the index already exists. Some drivers provide a cache mechanism to detect, without going to the server, if an index has been created (i.e. Python).

> The MongoDB server is restarted. Would a later call of ensureIndex() from a client application rebuild?

Same as above

> Is any of this affected by having multiple client sessions? I assume indexing is global across the entire collection per the documentation: "MongoDB defines indexes on a per-collection level."

Yes indexes are stored in MongoDB on the collection itself (to be technical, as a namespace within the `db.ns` file). Since it is a single point of knowledge for `ensureIndex` and an index is a single process (much like the write lock really) multiple connections should not effect whether the index creation is registered twice.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. MongoDB is not very clear about index persistance.