# Mongoose/Node server restart and duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Ok so after a ton of trial and error, I've determined that when I drop a collection and then recreate it through my app, unique doesn't work until I restart my local node server. Here's my Schema

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Services = new Schema ({ 
    type : {type : String},
    subscriptionInfo : Schema.Types.Mixed,
    data : Schema.Types.Mixed
},{_id:false});

var Hashtags = new Schema ({
    name: {type : String},
    services : [Services]
},{_id:false});

var SubscriptionSchema = new Schema ({
    eventId : {type: String, index: { unique: true, dropDups: true }}, 
    hashtags : [Hashtags]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Subscription', SubscriptionSchema);
```

And Here's my route...

```
router.route('/')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            var subscription = new subscribeModel();
            subscription.eventId = eventId;
            subscription.save(function(err, subscription) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                else
                    res.json({
                        message: subscription
                    });
            });
        })
```

If I drop the collection, then hit the /subscribe endpoint seen above, it will create the entry but will not honor the duplicate. It's not until I then restart the server that it starts to honor it. Any ideas why this is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What mongoose does when your application starts and it itself initializes is scan your schema definitions for the registered models and calls the [`.ensureIndexes()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes) method for the supplied arguments. This is the ["by design"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) behavior and is also covered with this statement:

> When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls ensureIndex for each defined index in your schema. While nice for development, it is recommended this behavior be disabled in production since index creation can cause a [significant performance impact](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-creation-operations). Disable the behavior by setting the autoIndex option of your schema to false.

So your general options here are:

1. Don't "drop" the collection and call `.remove()` which leaves the indexes intact.
2. Manually call [`.ensureIndexes()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.ensureIndexes) when you issue a drop on a collection in order to rebuild them.

The warning in the document is generally that creating indexes for large collections can take some time and take up server resources. If the index exists this is more or less a "no-op" to MongoDB, but beware of small changes to the index definition which would result in creating "additional" indexes.

As such, it is generally best to have a deployment plan for production systems where you determine what needs to be done.

Comment: Hey Neil, I appreciate your help. I'm kind of new to Mongo. So if there's any chance you can explain why it takes a restart to cause unique to work? I did check my debug logs and see that "subscriptions.ensureIndex" runs every restart but why is this different on a dropped collection the second time, after a document is created?

Comment: @GregThompson Perhaps the confusion here is in where MongoDB and mongoose will "create" the collection by default where it does not exist. So when you drop a collection you don't need to create it. The `.drop()` method will also drop indexes but the reverse does not apply to the collection creation. On the other hand `.ensureIndex()` **will** create a collection where none exists as well as creating the index. The mongoose `.ensureIndexes()` creates all indexes from the schema definition associated with the model.

Answer (score 0):

This post seems to argue that indexes are not re-built when you restart: [Are MongoDB indexes persistent across restarts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333331/are-mongodb-indexes-persistent-across-restarts)