# how to re initiate the collections metadata after database drop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using MongoDB to hold my data in the backend. and on the client side I have a button which is used to drop this database in order to reset everything and to start the system from the beginning once again:
[image]

On the backend, I am using mongoose (nodejs, expressJs, Mongoose, MongoDB).
and I am using this method to process this request and to drop the database and reset the system:

```js
mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase()
```

It works great, after clicking this red button, the client side rolls back to the Welcome page:

[image]

and I can start everything okay, until I reach that point where I want to register other users on the system,

I can register all the users with the same duplicate email address!

[image]

Which must be unique because that's how it's defined in the schema!

[image]

This is because the metadata doesn't get re-initialized after the database gets drop.

So how can I re-initiate the database metadata to hold the indexes, unique keys, sparse keys and so on?

## Before the drop:

[image]

## after the drop:

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I'd look into the answers on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901570/mongoose-node-server-restart-and-duplicates

In general - you want to either change how you clear your database (remove the data instead of dropping the db), or rebuild the indices after you drop the database.